# Como ler corretamente o símbolo ≤?

Tags: gramática

No contexto da matemática, o símbolo ≤ é utilizado para indicar que a quantidade que vem antes dele não é maior do que a quantidade que vem depois.

Por exemplo:

- A afirmação 7≤10 é verdadeira.
- A afirmação 2≤1 é falsa.
- A afirmação x≤y significa que x não é maior do que y.

Listo a seguir as maneiras mais comuns de ler a última expressão:

- x é **menor ou igual a** y.
- x é **menor do que ou igual a** y.
- x é **menor ou igual do que** y.

Existem livros com exemplos de todas estas formas. Alguma destas formas está incorreta do ponto de vista da gramática? Ou todas são aceitáveis?

Comment: A mesma pergunta com relação ao inglês: [Do we say “… is greater or equal to…” or “… is greater or equal than…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/38287).

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com Bechara, a primeira frase *x é menor ou igual a y* está correta consoante o autor, para alguns, a forma abreviada está correta; para outros, não segue o rigor da gramática, e se deveria escrever *x é menor (do) que y ou igual a y* ou variações, como *x é menor que y ou igual [a y]*.

A segunda *x é menor do que ou igual a y* aparenta ser *x é menor do que [y] ou igual a y*.

A terceira *x é menor ou igual do que y* me soa muito mal e não vejo por que *do que* iria de *menor do que* para frente de *igual*, visto *igual* usar a preposição *a*. Então, diria que está errada.

Comment: Concordo com o Bechara, "menor ou igual a" é provavelmente a única forma que já vi sendo usada na prática.

Comment: Qual é a referência do Bechara?

Comment: @Pedro, por ser um livro eu não coloquei o link, mas o nome é Moderna Gramática Portuguesa.

Comment: @Schilive Perguntei porque não estou muito familiarizado com esses autores. Mas qual seria a seção do livro em que ele aborda o assunto?

Comment: @Pedro, não sei a página, mas é a parte 6, de regência, item 6, se *item* é a palavra correta.

Comment: @stafusa e Schilive: Parece que a afirmação do autor sobre o tema é: "O rigor gramatical exige que não se dê complemento comum a termos de regência de
natureza diferente. [...] Salvo as situações de ênfase e de encarecimento semântico de cada preposição, como a que se depreende do trecho acima, a língua dá preferência às construções abreviadas que a gramática insiste em condenar, sem, contudo, obter grandes vitórias." Ele não está dizendo que do ponto de vista da gramática é errado omitir um dos complementos? Nesse trecho você entende que quem não obtém grandes vitórias (língua ou gramática)?

Comment: @Pedro Entendo que o autor diz que "a gramática insiste... sem... obter grandes vitórias", ou seja, que suas prescrições são consistentemente ignoradas pelos falantes nesse caso. Eu pessoalmente não creio que o "a" (de "igual a") se aplique ao "menor", mas sim que o "que" (em "menor que") esteja implícito, não violando realmente a prescrição (muito sensata) da gramática.